# apply Class OnChange in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i m creating no of `<li>... </li>` in javascript like this

```
$(function () {
    var settings = {
        rows: 6,
        cols: 6,
        rowCssPrefix: 'row-',
        colCssPrefix: 'col-',
        seatWidth: 30,
        seatHeight: 30,
        seatCss: 'seat',
        selectedSeatCss: 'selectedSeat',
        selectingSeatCss: 'selectingSeat'
    };

    var init = function (reservedSeat) {
        var str = [], seatNo, className;
        for (i = 0; i < settings.rows; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < settings.cols; j++) {

                seatNo = (i + j * settings.rows + 1);   
                className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString(); 
                str.push('<li id="'+seatNo+'" class="' + className  +" table"+seatNo+ '">' +'<a id="a'+ seatNo +'" title="'+ seatNo+'"></a>' '</li>');
            }
        }
        $('#place').html(str.join(''));

    };
```

Now i need to apply the Class `selectedSeat` to the `<li>`  ID's= 15 , 14 , 25, 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the the returned array, adding the class to all the specified elements.

```
$.each(selectDB, function() {
    $("li#" + this).addClass(settings.selectedSeatCss);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jdo9d6bp/4/)

In your `init` function, you should do:

```
className = settings.seatCss + ' ' + settings.rowCssPrefix + i.toString() + ' ' + settings.colCssPrefix + j.toString(); 
if ($.inArray(seatNo, reservedSeat) != -1) {
    className += ' ' + settings.selectedSeatCss
};
```

Comment: actually i need to apply the class selectedSeat to the < li > id's 15,14,25,10 (ex : li id =15 , li id=14 )

Comment: So use `#` instead of `.` to indicate an ID instead of class.

Comment: i tried  $("li#" + this). its not working.. the class selectedSeat is not applying to those ID < li >

Comment: but did't work for me, may be i have done some error in my code, any how Thank You.. i ll check my code

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with how you're setting the `selectDB` array.

Comment: there is already an another  init in code. Whether it make any problem ???     var bookedSeats = [ 12 ,10];
       init(bookedSeats);

Comment: I don't know what that's supposed to do, because your `init()` function doesn't use the argument.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to use `bookedSeats` to initialize the class. The `$.each` loop is for your AJAX callback to update the classes.

Comment: Ya its Working :D ThankYou :D I think i slept today :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59451/discussion-between-user3419304-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(selectDB, function(i, v) {
    $('#' + v).addClass("selectedSeat");
});
```